# Transformational geometry software

Tags: geometry

I'm doing a third year Geometry course involving transformations and isometries of the Euclidean plane. We're learning about the four isometries - rotation, reflection, translation and glide-reflection.
Is there any (free, preferably open source) software out there that can help me visualize these sorts of problems?

Comment: see http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/GeoGebraCalculus/GeoGebraCalculusApplets.html for a nice website introducing beautiful uses of Geogebra. Just two-dimensional though. There are a few 3D graphers, but I'm not aware of something which does in 3D what you ask here. Then again, I haven't googled it either...

Answer (score 1):

One could be [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php). I used it in a limited manner in my class while working on Euclidean Geometry. However, it is free to try, At an affordable low price, a license will make it easy to provide all students and teachers with a legal copy of Cinderella that they may use in school and at home.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I never heard of the program. +1

Comment: @amWhy: How are you? Miss you today... Long hours you've not been here. I could take some fishes today. Some of them is small but some is rather big. :-)

Comment: I see you've been "on a roll" with answers. Good for you!! (When I'm not at the clinic, I have work and chores to catch up on, and less time for Math.SE :-()

Answer (score 1):

The free program [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/) does all of these things. Versions of it are available for a wide variety of platforms. I have used it quite a lot, mainly for its graphing capabilities.

People have produced large numbers of *worksheets* that will enable you to explore transformations, and many other things geometrical.